# Generate Zip Codes Between two ranges

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am attempting to display all of the zip codes between two ranges in a database. My data looks something like this:

- Zip Start Zip End State
- 00501     06390    NY
- 10001     10314    NY
- 10451     11003    NY

I am hoping to display the data as

- 00501 NY
- 00502 NY
- 00503 NY
- 00504 NY
  ect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourTableName where CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING(yourZipCodeField, 0, 5)) AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 'FromRange' and 'ToRange'
```

hoping this could be helpful. as the above query self defines as took a substring, temporarily converted it to numeric value, and selected a range.